# Why is the ground mode the only excited mode in acoustics?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, waves, acoustics

If we take a disk of mass $m$ and area $A$ and place it in the middle of a pipe of length $L$ and section $A$ containg a fluid at pressure $P$ and temperature $T$ and closed from its two ends, the disk would be in equilibrium because the pressure on its two sides is the same.

However thermal fluctuations imply small instantenous shifts $\delta x$ of the disk from equilibrium $x=\frac{L}{2}$. The force on the disk is the difference of pressure times the area $\delta F=\delta P\times A$, and the pressure is proportional to the density $P\sim \frac{N}{V}$, so $\delta F\sim \frac{N}{(L+\delta x)}-\frac{N}{(L-\delta x)} \approx \frac{N}{L^{2}}\delta x$. Therefore the strength $k$ of the force restoring the disk to equilibrium is $k= \frac{\delta F}{\delta x}\sim \frac{N}{L^{2}}$.

For an ideal gas $P=\frac{Nk_{B}T}{V}$ this  means $k = \frac{Nk_{B}T}{L^{2}}$. The strength of the force effectively applied from each particle on the disk is $k = \frac{k_{B}T}{L^{2}}$. A mass $m$ subject to restoring force $k $ oscillates at $w=\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$ and thus moves at time-scale of $\tau=\frac{L}{v_{therm}}$, with $v_{therm}=\sqrt{\frac{k_{B}T}{m}}$. For a non-ideal gas the constant of proportionality between pressure and density is the sound velocity, instead of the thermal velocity $\tau=\frac{L}{v_{sound}}$. Overall, the estimation means that the resonance frequency is the time needed for a sound wave to propagate through the pipe thus implying a linear dependence of the resonance time on the pipe length $L$.

Coming to the question : The above considerations assume that the response is governed by the *harmonic ground frequency* of the fluid in the pipe. But a fluid in a pipe or any closed container should have multiple normal modes. So should these modes be expected to contribute to the response ?

In literature referring to acoustic resonance in pipes and other geometries I think this is somehow not discussed and empirically neglected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not surprising that researchers would have neglected to analyze the contributions of higher order harmonics. Generally, in most physical systems higher order modes contribute progressively less to the problem at hand. If researchers have neglected this, then it likely that any higher order effects are too small to make a meaningful difference.

Comment: I agree that this is seem in many systems. But is it possible to break this down to  a simple intuitive argument ? And how do you quantify this for the system presented here ?